# For every prime ideal $p$ the local ring $R_p$ has no nilpotent elements, then $R$ has no nilpotent elements

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Question:

> Let $R$ be a ring. Suppose that for every prime ideal $p \lhd R$ the local ring $R_p$ ($=(R\setminus p)^{-1}R$) has no non-zero nilpotent elements. Prove that $R$ has no non-zero nilpotent elements in this case. (*Hint: look at the nilradical of $R_p$?*)

I tried the following:

> Assume for contradiction $0\ne x\in R$ is a non-zero nilpotent element of $R$, so $x^n=0$ for some $n>1$. Now $\frac{x}{s}$ is in $R_p$ for any $s\in R\setminus p$. And $(\frac{x}{s})^n=\frac{x^n}{s^n}=\frac{0}{s^n}=\frac{0}{1}=0$. So $R_p$ has non-zero nilpotent elements, a contradiction. Therefore $R$ cannot have non-zero nilpotent elements.

My question: May I assume that $\frac{x}{s}$ is non-zero? If so, I seem to have found a proof which works, but doesn't use the nilradical. So what would a proof using the nilradical look like?

*In case it helps, I am going through Chapter 3 of Atiyah, MacDonald.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that $\frac{x}{1}=0$ implies that there is an $s\in S$ such that $xs=0$ (for example look at page 37 of Atiyah-MacDonald). Since $\operatorname{Ann(x)}$ is an ideal and $x$ is nilpotent, then there is a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $x^{n-1}\in\operatorname{Ann}(x)\subseteq\mathfrak{p}$ and $x\in\mathfrak{p}$. Thus by contraposition $\frac{x}{1}\neq 0$ in $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$.

---

Your proof is essentially a full write-down of the nilradical proof:

By *Corollary 3.12* if $\mathfrak{N}$ is the nilradical of $R$, then $\mathfrak{N}_\mathfrak{p}$ is the nilradical of $R_\mathfrak{p}$. Since being the $0$ module is a local property, $\mathfrak{N}_\mathfrak{p}=0$ for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subset R$ implies that $\mathfrak{N}=0$.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating a bit on the first part of your post? I can certainly see that $\frac{x}{1}=0$ implies $\exists s\in S=R\setminus p$ s.t. $xs=0$. I could derive from $xs=0\in p$ and $s\notin p$, that $x\in p$ (as $p$ is prime). But now I am stuck again.

Comment: I found a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ containing the annihilator of $x$, i.e. $\operatorname{Ann}(x)=\left\{r\in R \mid xr=0\right\}$. Therefore $xs\neq0$ for every $s\in S=R\setminus \mathfrak{p}$ since $S\cap \operatorname{Ann}(x)=\varnothing$, which by contraposition implies that $\frac{x}{1}\neq 0$. Then you can proceed with your argument, using $s=1$ and $p=\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Thanks again, unfortunately I fail to see why $\text{Ann}(x)$ is contained in a prime ideal (or especially in the prime ideal $p$). It's probably a simple fact. :/

Comment: Since $\operatorname{Ann}(x)$ is a proper ideal, it is contained in some maximal ideal (see *Corollary 1.4* in Atiyah-MacDonald), which is prime. For your argument to work you don't need it to be contained in *every* prime ideal of $R$, just in one of them, which I called $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot about "Suppose that for every prime ideal $p$ ...", I thought we had a fixed prime ideal. Hence my confusion. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @A.P. how you are sure that there exists a prime ideal p such that $x^{n-1} \in Ann(x) \subseteq p $ and $x\in p$? Can you please prove the existence of such a prime p?

Comment: 1 is not a member of Ann (x) , so Ann (x) is proper ideal of R and every proper ideal always contained in some maximal ideal and each maximal ideal is prime

Comment: @A.P. Sorry for the late comment. Why do we need the fact that $x^{n-1} \in \operatorname{Ann}(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in R$ such that $x^n=0$ for some $n$ and $U=Ann(x)=\{u \in R;~~ux=0\}$.

If we prove that $U=R$ then, in particular, $1\in U$ and therefore $x=0$.

Suppose that $U\subsetneq R$. Then there exists a maximal ideal $m\supset U$. Considere the localization $R_m$ and observe that

$$\left(\dfrac{x}{1}\right)^n = \dfrac{x^n}{1} = \dfrac{0}{1}.$$
So
$$\dfrac{x}{1} = \dfrac{0}{1}$$
and then $\exists u\in R\setminus m$ such that $ux=0$. That is a contradiction because $u\in R\setminus m$ implies $u\notin U$.

Therefore $U=R$ as we want to demonstrate.